# Is there an elegant (or more performant) way to (not) iterate through C# enums?

Tags: c#, performance

I have some enums like this:

```cs
internal enum CompanyA
{
    workerA = 21,
    workerB = 42,
}

internal enum CompanyB
{
    workerC = 22,
    workerD = 44,
}

internal enum CompanyA_Do
{
    DoA = 11,
    DoB = 5,
}

internal enum CompanyB_Do
{
    DoA = 15,
    DoB = 55,
}
```

I want to use the Environment.UserName to find out in which company the worker is employed.

If the Environment.UserName == workerA, then the company would be companyA.

Further, if isDoA == true, i want to get the int value from CompanyA_Do.DoA (value = 11).
Or if isDoB == true and the worker is an employee from CompanyA, then i want the value from CompanyA_Do.DoB (value = 5).

I could iterate through the enum CompanyA and CompanyB and do some if-statements to get the right value.

```cs
foreach (string employee in CompanyA.GetNames(typeof(CompanyA)))
{
    if (employee == Environment.UserName)
    {
        IsCompanA = true;
        if (isDoA) workerDoValue = (int) CompanyA_Do.DoA
        else if (isDoB) workerDoValue = (int) CompanyA_Do.DoB
        break;
    }
}
```

But i think this is messy solution. Especially, when i have 3 companies and plenty of worker. I need a loop for every company.

I wonder, if there is a more elegant approach to get the int-value from CompanyX_Do. Also, i shouldn't use a database. The program would run on different offline computers.

Comment: So everytime a company hires a new worker the application needs to be updated?
did you consider a database?

Comment: I would use a database, but the software should also run offline on different machines.

Comment: don't really get your statement, to me it sound like you are claiming that a database would prevent you from doing this. which isn't the case.

Comment: I suggest you use dictionary, that can easily be saved to disk for offline use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are using the correct level of abstraction. If your enums instead described the actual values of each type, like:

```
internal enum Company
{
    A,
    B,
}
internal enum Do
{
    A,
    B,
}
```

you can create mappings using dictionaries like

```
public Dictionary<string, Company> WorkerToCompany = new (){
   {"workerA", Company.A},
   {"workerC" , Company.B},
}
public Dictionary<(Company, Do), int> CompanyToDoValue = new (){
   {(Company.A, Do.A), 11},
   {(Company.A, Do.B), 5},
   {(Company.B, Do.B), 55},
}
```

Allowing you to write logic like

```
public int GetDoValue(string workerName, Do do){
   var company = WorkerToCompany[workerName];
   return CompanyToDoValue[(company, do)];
}
```

Note that using booleans, `isDoA` / `isDoB` has an obvious problem in that both can be either true or false, what should the value be in these cases? You may also need error handling to handle things like if the worker does not have a dictionary entry.